# Invoke-command localhost Access Denied

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

When Trying to invoke-Command against the Local Host I get access denied.

I have confirmed that PS remoting is enabled and the account is Administrator. Additionally Remoting in from remote machine works without issue.

```
Invoke-Command -computername LocalHost -scriptblock {hostname}
```

I expect to have the hostname of the local machine returned, however I receive Access denied Errors.

Comment: You have to be at an elevated prompt for localhost if you have UAC enabled.

Answer (score 0):

## Enable PSRemoting Service to Start Automatic

on both host and remote machines

```
Set-Service winrm -StartupType Automatic 
Start-Service winrm
```

## Enable PSREmoting

On both host and remote machines

```
EnablePSRemoting -Force
```

## Add computers to Trusted Hosts

On Remote machine

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "$(hostname),*$((Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)"
```

## Enable Multi Hopping in Powershell Remoting

Identify which hosts to allow passing of Creds

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP –Role Client –DelegateComputer   "$(hostname),*$((Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)"
```

On the source machine.

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP –Role Server
```

## You must specify Authentication and a Credential

on Host Machine

```
$Cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new("<username>",$("<Password>" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))
invoke-command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {Write-Host $args[0]} -ArgumentList "Hello!, It Works" -Authentication Credssp -Credential $cred
```

## REFERENCE

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6